# How to use Caliburn.Micro Event Aggregation handle a method that have return value?

Tags: wpf, mvvm, caliburn.micro

In MVVM, if we want to interact between viewmodels, we can use event aggregation to do this.

I know In Caliburn.Micro, we can implement the IHandle and IHandle(T) interface and write our own handle method.
But we can only write Handle method that without return value.
Like we can only implement the:

```
public void Handle()
{
}


public void Handle(T parameter)
{
}
```

What if i want to have a return value, like this:

```
public TResult Handle(T parameter)
{
}
```

Any help?

Comment: This isn't supported out of the box, and whilst you could theoretically do something like this, you would need to consider the implementation and how it would work.

The event aggregator is a subscriber service, which means that there could be many more than 1 listener for each event. 

If each event has many listeners, then many result values could be returned from many method calls making the caller implementation more complex.

Is there a good reason you want to do this?

Comment: Only the Conductor can execute the Show.Child<TView>().Configured(view=>view.Configure()); and it must return an IResult value, but i want to execute it in another viewmodel, so that's the reason.

Comment: Can you give a code example of your use case in your question please, it would be helpful! (pseudocode is fine!)

Answer (score 0):

Just publish another Message with your result. The sender of the first message subscribes to the second message.
Is this possible in your case?

this might be useful https://stackoverflow.com/a/23188060/736618